# Why is it mandatory to mention the Type information before the return type in case of static as well as non-static methods

Tags: java, generics, static

I need to understand the need of putting a Type before the return type in case of both, static and non-static classes. Is it only to ensure that the method abides by the type, or is there some other part of the story.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are talking about. Can you maybe illustrate your question with an example?

Comment: Are you talking about methods or classes?

Comment: Show some examples of what you mean, including an example of the way you _think_ it should be. The syntax is the syntax, there's not much point asking questions like this.  It's like asking "why does `=` mean assignment"?

Answer (score 0):

The language is designed this way.　If you don't like it, don't use Java. Try C# instead, where methods can be declared like this:

```
void MyMethod<T>(T someParam) { ... }
```

[JLS chapter 18](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html) shows that `TypeParameters` are declared as follows:

```
TypeParameters:
    < TypeParameter { , TypeParameter } >

TypeParameter:
    Identifier [extends Bound]

Bound:  
    ReferenceType { & ReferenceType }
```

And a `GenericMethodOrConstructorDecl` is defined like this:

```
GenericMethodOrConstructorDecl:
    TypeParameters GenericMethodOrConstructorRest

GenericMethodOrConstructorRest:
    (Type | void) Identifier MethodDeclaratorRest
    Identifier ConstructorDeclaratorRest
```

Here you can see that `TypeParameters` *precedes* `GenericMethodOrConstructorRest`.

As to why it is designed this way, I think the only effect this has is that it encourages you to think about the generic parameters first, then the return type.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you refer to this kind of method :

```
public <T> void myMethod(T t){
}
```

or

```
public <T> T myMethod(){
}
```

Specifying a `T` type in this way sets a constraint on parameters or the returned object.

When you declare a generic class you generally don't declare the type in the method as the type is already declared in the class :

```
public class MyGenericClass<T>{
```

For non generic classes, declaring a type in the method may be helpful.
There are multiple use cases.

It may for example allow to return a type according to the variable type assigned to the method by its caller.
The compiler may indeed use the target typing to infer the type of a generic method invocation.

For example you could define a method that converts one object to another type :

```
public <T>> convert(Object object, Class<T> clazz){
     ... // copy by reflection for example
    return (T) convertedObject;
 }
```

And you could invoke it in this way :

```
MyStringWrapper stringWrapper = convert("myString");
```